# AutoFixture customization for PagedList

Tags: autofixture, pagedlist

I am making my tests using AutoFixture but my interfaces return IPagedList instead of IList. The problem is that AutoFixture generates empty paged lists. I am new to AutoFixture so probably my solution (which by the way does not work properly) is not the best. See what I did:

```
public class PagedListCustomization<TEntity> : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<IPagedList<TEntity>>(c => c.FromFactory(
                () =>
                {
                    var list = fixture.CreateMany<TEntity>();
                    int pageSize = fixture.Create<int>();
                    int pageIndex = fixture.Create<int>();
                    return list.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                }));
        }
    }


.......


var fixture = new Fixture()
 .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
 .Customize(new MvcCustomization())
 .Customize(new MultipleCustomization())
 .Customize(new PagedListCustomization<TEntity>());
```

The problem is that the paged list is still empty but I think it is because probably the pageIndex is too large.

My questions are:
1) How can I manage the pageIndex to be less than list.Count() and greater than zero?
2) Is there a more appropriate way to setup this?

Thank you so much!!! There is so little doc about AutoFixture...

Update: I am so far using this but looks overkill:

```
int pageSize = new Generator<int>(fixture).First(n => n > 0 && n <= list.Count);
                int pageIndex = new Generator<int>(fixture).First(n => n > 0 && n < list.Count/pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The order of customizations matter](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter). I haven't tried, but it'd probably help reordering the customizations:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new PagedListCustomization<TEntity>())
    .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
    .Customize(new MvcCustomization());
```

Also, you shouldn't need `MultipleCustomization` since AutoFixture 3.0.